# Cannot install tweepy on Rasbian with sudo pip install

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tweepy

I am trying to make a Twitter app with my Pi but when I try the command

```
sudo pip install tweepy
```

I get greeted by the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'skip_requirements_regex'
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/pi/build/tweepy
```

Any suggestions? This also happens if I try to install directly from GitHub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone on the Raspberry Pi forums figured out the problem. Apparently there is a problem installing some applications with pip v1.1, which is the version in the Raspbian repository. Updating pip with the following command did the trick.

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried installing it from the source?

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Yes, It has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Someone had a similar question. Here is the link on github.
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/441

If that doesn't help you can go on the link of the main page

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

and then click download zip on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried "sudo pip install -U pip"

but still got errors but looking at [documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/install.html) found better option.

```
easy_install tweepy
```

and it worked as expected.